# How to tell if a long-running API call is still running, or has failed unexpectedly

Tags: rest, scheduled-tasks

We've got a scheduled task (using a custom Windows Service) that calls an API endpoint every 5 minutes.  Usually, this endpoint finishes within the 5 minutes, but occasionally it takes longer - in those cases, when the scheduled task calls the API the next time, the API knows that the previous request is still processing and so skips the processing that time.  This continues until the original request completes, then the next time the API is called, processing begins again.  This means we never get overlapping processing.

We record these states in a database, where we store when a processing starts and finishes.  When the API is called, it checks these states and if there's a process recorded that hasn't finished yet, it knows a process is on-going, and so skips it.

If the process throws an exception, then the API updates the state in the database, so the next request to the API knows it can safely start because the last one has failed.

This all works fine when the API can update the state when an exception is thrown, however we've had a case when the API request has immediately stopped, and didn't get a chance to update the state in the database.  As a result, subsequent calls to the API all assumed that processing was still on-going, and didn't process anything again.

Is there a good pattern or approach we can use to avoid this situation?  Is there a way to accurately record when an API process is running, and when it has failed (even if it's not possible to log anything during the failure)?

Comment: When exactly such error case happened? If it was server shut down then you can do nothing with that. Only delete such data from database. Was it some other case?

Comment: @Mara I don't exactly know what happened - all I got was an error in the server event logs that the connection was closed.  I'll need to handle the situation when the server is shut off as well, though.